# Display html within Extjs panel for IE browser

Tags: html, internet-explorer, extjs, xhtml

I have an ExtJS application that needs to display an html document within a panel. The application works fine in FF and chrome However, when I attempt to use this functionality inside Internet Explorer 8 a pop-up appears:

> "Do you want to save this file, or find a program online to open it?
>   Name: getBinary Type: Unknown File Type, 688KB  From:
>   SERVER_NAME_HERE"

I have not included the code because it's my company's property but could probably create a mock-up if it's really needed. I first wanted to see if there was any common knowledge on this type of issue that I haven't been able to find online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out and have to apologize to the good people here at stackoverflow. IE8 was not having trouble displaying a .html page. The page was actually a .xhtml file which I learned by digging deeper into the code, one of our developers just named it .html :/

So there are two different solutions to get internet explorer 8 to display a .xhtml file.

1. You can use the hack/fix mentioned here [w3c xhtml fix](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/2004/xhtml-faq#ie)
2. You can change the .xhtml file's extension to .html (this is more risky) but in my particular case no additional information was being lost.